# Issue with Mysql SUM and GROUP_CONCAT in query

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I am having issue with my query having both `SUM` and `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

The sum values changes as `GROUP_CONCAT` values increases.

Below is my code:

```
SELECT     ul.display_name, 
           ul.photo, 
           ul.user_id, 
           Sum(ulr.level_score)              AS level_scores, 
           Sum(ulr.level_timer)              AS level_timer, 
           Group_concat(ulr.level_completed) AS levels, 
           Group_concat(DISTINCT c.bit_id)   AS bit_id 
FROM       user_level_responses              AS ulr 
INNER JOIN user_login                        AS ul 
ON         ( 
                      ul.user_id=ulr.user_id) 
INNER JOIN c_member AS cm 
ON         ( 
                      cm.user_id=ul.user_id 
           AND        cm.user_approval='Y' 
           AND        cm.delete_status='0' 
           AND        cm.status='1') 
INNER JOIN ctree ct 
ON         ( 
                      cm.circuit_id=ct.circuit_id ) 
INNER JOIN cir AS c 
ON         ( 
                      c.circuits_id=cm.circuit_id 
           AND        c.builtin=0 
           AND        c.delete_status='0' 
           AND        c.status='1') 
WHERE      Match(ct.circuit_path) against ('_902_') 
AND        ulr.institution_id=321 
AND        ulr.delete_status=0 
AND        ulr.status=1 
AND        ul.delete_status=0 
GROUP BY   ulr.user_id 
ORDER BY   level_scores DESC, 
           level_timer ASC, 
           ul.display_name limit 500
```

If the actual score is 900 and if i have 2 ids in `GROUP_CONCAT` then actual score is double the original.

```
Expected OUTPUT:

user1   2010.cs,btech   960 00:01:08    Completed
user2   btech   920 00:01:08    Completed

OUTPUT GETTING:

user1   2010.cs,btech   1920    00:01:08    Completed
user2   btech   920 00:01:08    Completed
```

twice the actual amount ie 960.

Comment: do you have problem with `SUM` or `GROUP_CONCAT` ? Can you please provide here expected sample data and actual sample data?

Comment: If user_login, c_member, c_tree or cir have two possible rows that can join in at any time, that would double your results.  I assume user_login is not the culpret because user_id should be unique, but since we don't know the nature of any of the rest it's hard to pin down which it could be.

Comment: @trex005 the user can have multiple ids which is group_concated using query... yes u are right as first row has 2 ids thats why the score is doubled.... anyway to bypass this...as user can be part of many groups and its id is c.bit_id

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia updated my question

Comment: @user3797205 There lies your problem.  If your c.id is doubled, the query (before grouping) will have twice as many rows to group, thus doubling everything.  You can solve this with a subquery.

Comment: @trex005 thanks your suggestion helped.... resolved the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your multiple ids are doubling the rows that your result has before the grouping.  You can solve this problem by joining in all of the external data in a subquery.

I have absolutely no idea the structure of your database, nor all of the functions, but this is a stab in the dark at reorganizing your query.  If you need, I can write up a much simpler SQLFiddle to show you what I mean.

```
SELECT     ul2.display_name, 
           ul2.photo, 
           ul2.user_id, 
           Sum(ulr.level_score)              AS level_scores, 
           Sum(ulr.level_timer)              AS level_timer, 
           Group_concat(ulr.level_completed) AS levels, 
           ul2.bit_id
FROM       user_level_responses              AS ulr
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
    ul.display_name,
    ul.photo,
    ul.user_id,
    GROUP_CONTACT(DISTINCT c.bit_id)  as bit_id
    FROM       user_login                        AS ul 
    INNER JOIN c_member AS cm 
    ON         ( 
                  cm.user_id=ul.user_id 
           AND        cm.user_approval='Y' 
           AND        cm.delete_status='0' 
           AND        cm.status='1') 
    INNER JOIN ctree ct 
    ON         ( 
                  cm.circuit_id=ct.circuit_id ) 
    INNER JOIN cir AS c 
    ON         ( 
                  c.circuits_id=cm.circuit_id 
           AND        c.builtin=0 
           AND        c.delete_status='0' 
           AND        c.status='1') 
    WHERE      Match(ct.circuit_path) against ('_902_') 
    AND        ul.delete_status=0
    GROUP BY   ul.user_id
) AS ul2
ON  (
        ulr.user_id = ul2.user_id )
WHERE      ulr.institution_id=321 
AND        ulr.delete_status=0 
AND        ulr.status=1 
GROUP BY   ulr.user_id
ORDER BY   level_scores DESC, 
           level_timer ASC, 
           ul.display_name limit 500
```

Comment: First of all thanks to trex005 for helping me out.... but when i explain this query it is having huge effect on performance as i am doing left join on query...... hence i changed the logic and added subquery after where condition.....